# how to make password-less authentication in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have several roles of users such as "master admin", "employees", etc. Master admin can see list of all users, their usernames and roles. My requirement is:

- Master admin should be able to logout himself and login as a particular user without a password. from the list of users.
- Is this a good practice?, does this cause potential security vulnerabilities?

Edit: This application is used internally within an organization.

Comment: Depends on what those users have in your app, but everything about this solution screams "NO, JUST DON'T" to me. If you need to be able to see what a user can do, just make a test user with the same permissions. Taking over people's accounts is dangerous at best and downright illegal at worst.

Comment: You could implement a impersonate function for testing and customer support. Make sure to remove personal data. You should be able to read data. For internal use i would recommend this option

Answer (score 0):

You could use following plugin: [viacreative/sudo-su](https://github.com/viacreative/sudo-su)

It's ment for development but it should work just fine in your case. If you want to use it in production you could add some restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default laravel authentication:

```
Auth::logout(); // Logout from current user
Auth::login($user); // Login as the selected user
```

This approach has some concerns:

1. The master admin credentials become MASSIVE. If an attacker is able to 
   impersonate a master admin (by stoling their credentials or by using some other vulnerability in your code) then it would be able to login as *everyone else*. Of course it is always bad that an attacker is able to impersonate an user, but in this case it would be even more dangerous.
2. It is a bit rude, as a user, to have someone else logging in as me without my consent. As an internal tool within an organization, this concern may not be so important
3. In case there are some data-protection and privacy policies applied, this solution would invalidate them all because a master admin could see the data of every user without their consent

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with using this package. It works fine for my requirement.

https://github.com/404labfr/laravel-impersonate